# How to use my Laptop as a web Server using Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: webserver

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and I want to use as a webserver for my domain. Also I want to install Wordpress on the domain. I want to how can i do that. And help, please

Answer (score 1):

I think that all you need to know and to do is to be found in the [Wordpress documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress).